# How to build angular main.js under assets folder

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-cli-v11

I have an Angular app, is there a way that I can force Angular to deploy the main.js under /assets folder?

basically I want to make Angular-CLI compile main.ts to main.js in assets folder.

```
"build": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
      "options": {
        "outputPath": "dist/myprofile",
        "index": "src/index.html",
        "main": "src/main.ts",
        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
        "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
        "assets": [
          "src/favicon.ico",
          "src/assets"
        ],
        "styles": [              
          "src/styles.scss"
        ]
      },
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "assets": [
            {
              "glob": "**/*",
              "input": "src/assets",
              "output": "/assets/",
              "ignore": [
                "appConfig.dev.json"
              ]
            },
            {
              "glob": "favicon.ico",
              "input": "src/",
              "output": "/"
            }
          ]
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to change other property.

```
"outputPath": "/assets",
```

this shows angular where output should be placed

Comment: I don't want to put everything in the assets folder. This will create an assets folder and compile and build everything in that folder. I only want to build the js files in the assets folder

Comment: u can extend npm script `npm build :"ng build ... && cp dist/main.js ./assets"`